# Avoid Death by dpkg-triggers?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-16.04, dpkg

*You don't really need to know anything about the technologies I'm using to answer my question*. You only need to understand dpkg and its triggers.

I'm using an orchestration tool (mcollective) to trigger configuration management (puppet 3) on some remote hosts running Ubuntu 16.04. Puppet uses apt-get to install some packages that I need to update. The packages include files that go in a directory owned by mcollective. Looks like this:

```
mcollective > puppet > apt-get > dpkg > /some/dir/mcollective/myfile > dpkg-trigger
```

The problem is, when dpkg processes post-install triggers, it restarts mcollective (which has a trigger on the directory). Stopping mcollective kills puppet, apt-get, and dpkg itself.

After this none of the processes above will be running, which means I can't use mcollective to control the host anymore. I have to manually log in and fix everything (including `dpkg --configure -a` before any apt-get stuff will work).

The question: **Is there any way I can update the .deb to not trigger the restart of mcollective?** Something I can put in the control file, perhaps?

Comment: Err, did you package mcollective yourself rather than using a Puppet Labs provided package or a Debian/Ubuntu provided package?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's not mcollective I'm installing. It's a set of custom mcollective agents (plugins, if you will). The agents must be installed in a subdirectory of mcollective, but altering anything in that directory triggers the restart.